# How to Insert Outlet and connect image to the code in Xcode version 11.5

Tags: xcode

I need to connect my image to the code and create Outlet in X-code version 11.5 ,

In X-code version 9 its just hold down control + Click Image + Drag to the code file then it will create connection link outlet.

But in X-code version 11.5 its not working as version 9 .
when I drag to the code its not show the blue line in view controller code.

Any help please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follow the following steps and it will work with you :

1- Open X-code version 11.5

2- create new project

3- Select Single View App in a template for your new project then click next

4- In the next window type your project name

5- select the team by connect to your apple store ID and type your password

6- Type organization name and Organization Identifier

7- In the Language field select Swift

8- In User Interface change SwiftUI and select StoryBoard (This is the important
selection).

9- Click next then in the next screen select where to create project folder and save

10- Add new ImageView then try to insert the outlet to your ViewController.swift file I think this will solve your issue .

The error because you select when create new project in User interface SwiftUI not StoryBoard.